# JS innerHTML not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, innerhtml

I'm trying to create a dynamic navbar that is different when a user is signed in vs. not signed in.

I have the auth portion working (confirmed with console logs); however, for some reason, the HTML is not getting updated when I use `.innerHTML = ...`. I'm console logging the innerHTML after I update it, and it appears correct in the log but the navbar isn't displaying like it should.

HTML:

```
...
<ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
    <li id ="nav-listings">
        <a href="Search.html" class="nav-link"><strong>Listings</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
    <li class="has-children" id="nav-account">
        <a href="Signin.html" class="nav-link"><strong>Sign-In</strong></a>
        <div id="navDropdown" class="dropdown">
            <a href="User.html">Profile</a>
            <a href="Signup.html">Sign-Up</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
...
```

js code:

```
AOS.init({
    duration: 800,
    easing: 'slide',
    once: true
 });

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    "use strict";


    $(".loader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
    $("#overlayer").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");

...

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            var username = firebaseUser.email;
            console.log(`${firebaseUser ? `- User signed in: ${firebaseUser.email} => ${username}` : "No User Signed in"}`);
            
            document.getElementById("nav-listings").className = "has-children";
            document.getElementById("nav-listings").innerHTML = "<a href='Search.html' class='nav-link'><strong>Listings</strong></a>" +
                                                                "<div id='listDropdown' class='dropdown'>" +
                                                                    "<a href='AddHouse.html'>Add Listing</a>" +
                                                                    "<a href='User.html'>Favorites</a>" + 
                                                                "</div>";
            console.log(document.getElementById("nav-listings").innerHTML);
        } else {
            btnLogin.disabled = false;
        }
    });
 });
```

**EDIT:**
It is appearing in the condensed form of the navbar but the main navbar???
See [Here](https://codepen.io/nstory/pen/abNGoRj) for the full code (minus the CSS... which makes the problem hard to see but all the js and HTML are there).

Comment: provide a codepen example for quick debugging

Comment: How many elements with id="nav-listings" do you have on your page ?
You are using jquery , so why don't you use `$("#nav-listings").html('My HTML here');` ?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, although you do have an incorrect space in the id of the element you're trying to select. `id ="nav-listings"` should be `id="nav-listings"`. That may be messing you up.

Comment: @angel.bonev Only one element has that id. I tried that as well with no luck.

Comment: @MrKhan [link](https://codepen.io/nstory/pen/abNGoRj) No CSS but here it is

Answer (score 1):

This should work

HTML:

```
<ul class="site-menu main-menu js-clone-nav mr-auto d-none d-lg-block">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
    <li id="nav-listings">
        <a href="Search.html" class="nav-link"><strong>Listings</strong></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
    <li class="has-children" id="nav-account">
        <a href="Signin.html" class="nav-link"><strong>Sign-In</strong></a>
        <div id="navDropdown" class="dropdown">
            <a href="User.html">Profile</a>
            <a href="Signup.html">Sign-Up</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            var username = firebaseUser.email;
            console.log(`${firebaseUser ? `- User signed in: ${firebaseUser.email} => ${username}` : "No User Signed in"}`); ;
            $("#nav-listings").addClass('has-children').html("<a href='Search.html' class='nav-link'><strong>Listings</strong></a><div id='listDropdown' class='dropdown'><a href='AddHouse.html'>Add Listing</a><a href='User.html'>Favorites</a></div>")
            console.log($("#nav-listings").html());
        } else {
            btnLogin.disabled = false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the innerHTML you are also setting the class for nav-listings to has-children. This removes the existing class of nav-link.

Do you mean to do this? If you want to keep the nav-link class as well then instead of

`document.getElementById("nav-listings").className = "has-children"`;

put a space before the has-children and add the string to the classname. This will then add has-children to the class and wont remove the nav-link.

`document.getElementById("nav-listings").className += " has-children"`;

If you console.log the outerHTML instead of innerHTML you can check whether both nav-link and has-children are there.

Comment: Thank you for this, I know I would have run into this problem later if you hadn't brought it up. This doesn't solve the problem though, it's something weird with the bootstrap I think. See the edit ^